# Could Mouse-Over a post in chat show the timestamp?

Tags: feature-request, chat, timestamps, tooltips

When you mouse over a chat message nothing happens.

I think there should be some tooltip with more info about the post.  I'd prefer an exact timestamp.

In most (all?) other areas of the main sites, if you mouseover a time, you are shown an exact timestamp.  Chat shouldn't be different.

Comment: I think timestamp is a great idea. The occasional random timestamp on the side isn't very sufficient at times.

Comment: Isn't this done already?  Mousing over shows the drop-down on the left side, which includes a timestamp and a bunch of other options. A tooltip wouldn't really add much...

Comment: @Aarobot, I see 'click for message actions'?

Comment: Just to note discussion from chat, the UTC time is available already, if you open the drop down menu and mouse over the time ..  '49s ago' [as noted by Tim](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/691681#691681)

Comment: @Aaro, no, like you said, it doesn't show a tooltip on mouseover.

Comment: "If you mouseover a time, you are shown an exact timestamp. Chat shouldn't be different." As M. Tibbits says, it *isn't* different. Just click the arrow on the left to see all the information you're asking for. If you're asking why that same information isn't a tooltip by default... that would be pretty annoying.

Comment: I think this should be implemented in the same way the normal timestamps appear: a thing on the right of the post that would appear the instant the cursor hovers over it. This would a) eliminate wait time vs. the tooltip and b) eliminate clicks vs. the drop-down menu.