# show Z timestamp in chat transcript

Tags: feature-request, chat, timestamps, chat-transcript

There is no way currently (that I found) where the Z timestamp (or any timestamp for that matter) for chat messages in chat transcript is shown. The only way to find when the message was sent is to go to the edit history and then you get a to-the-minute accurate timestamp.

I suggest adding the standard Z timestamp to the popup.

While you are at it you could also add it to the [normal chat room screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57246/could-mouse-over-a-post-in-chat-show-the-timestamp).